# Symfony 3 inside subdirectory

Tags: php, symfony

Short story to the context:

I have a domain where most of my projects are hosted under a subdirectory simply called 'projects', most stuff is not built upon a framework, neither the website itself. Last year I discovered Symfony and played a bit around with it, kinda liked it. Just for fun I 'ported' one project into Symfony (v. 3.1.4) and from then on only worked on this Symfony project. Some days ago I wanted to upload that Symfony project to my website.

I just have the problem that I can't seem to get it running inside that subdirectory. I also don't really want to create a sub-domain just for that project - it's inconsistent and I don't feel like it 'deserves' a sub-domain, as it's a smaller project.. :D

I already searched around but most questions and answers are for Symfony 2 (things changed a bit) and a [more recent blog entry](https://www.yegods.it/2015/01/30/install-symfony-app-in-a-subfolder-of-an-existing-site/) doesn't seem to work for me, or maybe I did sth. wrong..

Comment: Symfony hasn't any problems running inside a directory. The only thing you should care about is putting the right paths in your `.htaccess` file (inside the `web` folder). I guess the problem is not related to this but to the `var/cache` and `var/logs` folders and their permissions... Does the user who runs the webserver (apache, www-data, _www...?) have permissions to write to these folders?

Comment: Well, that could be a problem.. I also couldn't delete the `var/logs` folder, when I removed it after I just couldn't get it to work. FileZilla shows me it has no permissions for that.. It has standard 755 rights, though.

Comment: It is a very common problem on shared hostings. You could create a very simple PHP script to recursively change permissions of these folders to 777 and try it again.

Comment: The folder still can't be removed - `550 logs No permission`. Maybe the hoster has a deletion blacklist for 'logs' folders? There also is one in the root.. But well, I don't think this is the problem here, is it? I also tried creating a simple test.php in the Symfony web directory - had no problem calling and running that file in the browser..

Comment: If Symfony cannot write to logs and cache directory, it will not work. Maybe you should ask your hosting provider to change these folders' permissions...